# PHP 7.0.23 extensions unavailable after upgrade

Tags: php

On x64 ubuntu 16.04.1 , after upgrading PHP from 7.0.22 (apg-get install) to PHP 7.0.23 (built from source)
my previously working php extensions are not available , don't show in getAvailableDrivers().

I use CLI.

The previous PHP 7.0.22 used /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini and this file is not changed and still mentions my extensions.
The previous PHP had the extensions in path /usr/lib/php/20151012

php -v shows 7.0.23 and no errors.
getAvailableDrivers only shows sqlite.

I use CLI, and copied the old php.ini to /usr/local/lib , and phpinfo() now shows :

```
...
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/local/lib
Loaded Configuration File => /usr/local/lib/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => (none)
Additional .ini files parsed => (none)
...
extension_dir => /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012 => /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012
...
```

I copied the extensions to /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012
I copied the old php.ini file to /usr/local/lib/php, and /usr/local/lib, but this did not fix it. 
I also rebuilt from source one of the extensions and installed it again.
These actions did not fix the problem or change the symptom, so I've clearly made a mistake or missed some steps. Any advice?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: I'd advise going back to the package managed version and waiting a little while for the 7.0.23 version to be released there.